# Not showing components following format LinearLayout inside GridLayout contains CardView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout, cardview

I am implementing card view through `GridLayout` in android but my card view is not showing up. I want to display main layout is Liner Layout inside Grid Layout its contain Card View  . I have tried all things but the card view is not showing up.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapps"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="3">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:text="Calendar"
                    android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

÷ hope any one fix this problem.

Comment: Just remove android:layout_gravity="center" from `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the height of the `ScrollView` as wrap_content as its height is determined at runtime. and also the same for its nested `LinearLayout`

To make the `ImageView` & `TextView` visible use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` for their surrounding `LinearLayout`

so change your layout to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapps"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

> **Edit:**
>   Anyone explain why its not showing my `GridLayout` width as `match_parent`
>
> **I want this :**

[image]

Solution:

Changes:

1. Making `Gridlayout` width to match_parent
2. Adding `android:layout_gravity="center"` to the Gridlayout
3. Making the width & height of all `CardViews` and underlying
   `LinearLayouts` to "wrap_content" >>>>>> This is the real cause to
   the problem.
4. Making `android:gravity="center"` to the `CardViews` underlying
   `LinearLayout` for symmetric purpose >> you can leave it as `center_vertical` if you wish.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapps"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="50dp"
            android:rowCount="2">
            <!--            First Row , First Column -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"

                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <!--            First Row , Second Column-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <!--            Second Row , First Column-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <!--            Second Row , Second Column-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @GaneshMB welcome .. I just saw your answer in this thread.. it would be better to update you question or open a new question so that some one can notice it's a part of a question and offer help to you.. and I will try to solve it for you man

Comment: Hello @GaneshMB .. I want to know please do you want to get 4 cards on top of each others like in a square, but make your GridView bounds to the screen borders ?

Comment: yep please check out my Image , i want to UI like this

Comment: @GaneshMB now check changes please

Comment: yes @Zain thats actually i want this UI design , and `android:columnOrderPreserved` ,  `android:alignmentMode`  `app:cardElevation` this is what happen to  affect UI Design?

Answer (score 1):

you can ConstrainLayout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Zain your answer is work well , but i have a one more mistake in `GridLayout` when i try to make GridLayout width as `match_parent` its not showing anything so i change as `Layout_Width` ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bgapps"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"     // here i want to match_parent
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="50dp"
            android:rowCount="2">
<!--            First Row , First Column -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
<!--            First Row , Second Column-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
<!--            Second Row , First Column-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
<!--            Second Row , Second Column-->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Calendar"
                        android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                        android:textSize="14dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Anyone explain why its not showing my `GridLayout` width as `match_parent`

**I want this :**

[image: I want this kind of View]